# Start a New Page with PDFKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdfkit

I'm using PDFKit in Rails that displays tables from my db. I want each table to have its own separate page. How can I achieve this?

```
html = "<p>HTML content here</p>"

kit = PDFKit.new(html, :page_size => 'Letter')
  output = kit.to_pdf

respond_to do |format|

format.pdf do
  send_data output, :filename => "trading_analysis.pdf",
                    :type => "application/pdf"
  end
end
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a `page break` as of such?

Comment: Correct, that's what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay not sure if this maybe what you are exactly looking for but it is certainly most worth considering. You could alternatively look at using wickedpdf and then wrapping a `div` around your content and the following in your CSS.

```
div.page {
  width: 180mm;
  height: 277mm;
  overflow: hidden;
  page-break-before: always;
}
```

*EDIT:* `page-break-after: always;` added a blank page at times, so we should use `page-break-before: always;`

Comment: I think we should be using `page-break-before: always;`, otherwise an blank pages is added at the bottom.